# iOS In app purchase : request latest cancellation date and number of cancellations

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am working with iOS In-App Purchase.

I would like to request the latest cancellation date and the total number of cancellations preferably with 100% correct result.

I am using Apple's verifyreceipt call

```
(
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1 
-> 
https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt 
/ 
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt 
JSON response field descriptions : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW25
) .
```

The JSON response has this format :

```
(lldb) po jsonResponse
{
    environment = Sandbox;
    "latest_receipt" = "<some binary text>";
    "latest_receipt_info" =     (
                {
            "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 15:41:31 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1510933291000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:41:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = true;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
            "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
            "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:31 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1510929691000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036932780;
        },
                {
            "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 15:46:31 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1510933591000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:46:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
            "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
            "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 15:41:31 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1510933291000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:41:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000353176570;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036932781;
        },
                {
            "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 15:51:31 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1510933891000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:51:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
            "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
            "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 15:46:31 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1510933591000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:46:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000353177515;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933429;
        },
                {
            "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 15:56:31 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1510934191000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:56:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
            "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
            "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 15:51:31 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1510933891000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:51:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000353178539;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933488;
        },
                {
            "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 16:01:31 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1510934491000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 08:01:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
            "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
            "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 15:56:31 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1510934191000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:56:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000353179673;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933554;
        },
                {
            "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 16:06:31 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1510934791000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 08:06:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
            "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
            "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 16:01:31 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1510934491000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 08:01:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000353180672;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933616;
        },
                {
            "expires_date" = "2017-11-18 16:03:15 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1511020995000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-18 08:03:15 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
            "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
            "purchase_date" = "2017-11-18 15:58:15 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1511020695000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-18 07:58:15 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000353294875;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933659;
        }
    );
    "pending_renewal_info" =     (
                {
            "auto_renew_product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
            "auto_renew_status" = 1;
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
            "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
        }
    );
    receipt =     {
        "adam_id" = 0;
        "app_item_id" = 0;
        "application_version" = 759;
        "bundle_id" = "com.myapp";
        "download_id" = 0;
        "in_app" =         (
                        {
                "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 15:46:31 Etc/GMT";
                "expires_date_ms" = 1510933591000;
                "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:46:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
                "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
                "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 15:41:31 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1510933291000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:41:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000353176570;
                "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036932781;
            },
                        {
                "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 15:51:31 Etc/GMT";
                "expires_date_ms" = 1510933891000;
                "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:51:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
                "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
                "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 15:46:31 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1510933591000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:46:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000353177515;
                "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933429;
            },
                        {
                "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 15:56:31 Etc/GMT";
                "expires_date_ms" = 1510934191000;
                "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:56:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
                "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
                "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 15:51:31 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1510933891000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:51:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000353178539;
                "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933488;
            },
                        {
                "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 16:01:31 Etc/GMT";
                "expires_date_ms" = 1510934491000;
                "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 08:01:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
                "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
                "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 15:56:31 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1510934191000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:56:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000353179673;
                "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933554;
            },
                        {
                "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 16:06:31 Etc/GMT";
                "expires_date_ms" = 1510934791000;
                "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 08:06:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
                "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
                "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 16:01:31 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1510934491000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 08:01:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000353180672;
                "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933616;
            },
                        {
                "expires_date" = "2017-11-18 16:03:15 Etc/GMT";
                "expires_date_ms" = 1511020995000;
                "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-18 08:03:15 America/Los_Angeles";
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
                "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
                "purchase_date" = "2017-11-18 15:58:15 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1511020695000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-18 07:58:15 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000353294875;
                "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036933659;
            },
                        {
                "expires_date" = "2017-11-17 15:41:31 Etc/GMT";
                "expires_date_ms" = 1510933291000;
                "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 07:41:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                "is_trial_period" = true;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:34 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1510929694000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:34 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
                "product_id" = "com.myapp.iap.pro.renewing.monthly.trial";
                "purchase_date" = "2017-11-17 14:41:31 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1510929691000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-17 06:41:31 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000353161868;
                "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000036932780;
            }
        );
        "original_application_version" = "1.0";
        "original_purchase_date" = "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT";
        "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1375340400000;
        "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";
        "receipt_creation_date" = "2017-11-18 15:58:18 Etc/GMT";
        "receipt_creation_date_ms" = 1511020698000;
        "receipt_creation_date_pst" = "2017-11-18 07:58:18 America/Los_Angeles";
        "receipt_type" = ProductionSandbox;
        "request_date" = "2017-11-18 15:58:23 Etc/GMT";
        "request_date_ms" = 1511020703927;
        "request_date_pst" = "2017-11-18 07:58:23 America/Los_Angeles";
        "version_external_identifier" = 0;
    };
    status = 0;
}
```

I don't see any way to extract the "number of cancellations" info from this response. Is there any way to do it? Possibly using a different request for example?

As I see I can get the "latest cancellation date" by checking the value of "pending_renewal_info" : "auto_renew_status" == 0 and iterating over the array of receipts and getting the latest expiration date (maybe with adding a safety check that it is less than the current date).
But : as I see this solution does not give 100% correct result, because : 
in case if a user has a cancelled subscription and renews it outside the app without starting the app, my app won't be able to identify that cancellation.
Is there any way to request this information?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "number of cancellations"? Do you mean number of times a single user has cancelled or the number of cancellations across all of your users?

Comment: @JacobEiting : I mean the "number of times a single user has cancelled".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to compute the total number of cancellations by looping over all your receipts, calling verify, and checking the `pending_renewal_info` for all the products that you care about.

This method **will** give you a correct result at the time it is called. `pending_renewal_info` isn't actually intrinsic to the receipt but is returned by Apple's servers with the latest info. So if a user cancels, this will be reflected here. In fact, when a user cancels, the receipt itself doesn't change at all and your app doesn't receive any new transactions, the only way to know is by hitting the `verifyReceipt` endpoint.

If you want to see the number of times an individual user has cancelled, this information isn't available via `pending_renewal_info`. You would need to look at the individual transactions in the `latest_receipt_info` field and do a comparison of `purchase_date`, `expires_date` and the duration of the product to find gaps in the users subscription. If there are gaps that are more than a few days you should be able to consider that a cancellation period.

Comment: verifyReceipt expects to receive base64 encoded receipt data in the "receipt-data" JSON field. I don't receive the binary format for these receipts so I can't loop over them and send them to verifyReceipt. Is it possible to generate them somehow using the received JSON response? (I quoted that response in my original post.)

Comment: Updated my answer (last paragraph) with how I would do it. It's not immediately available in `pending_renewal_info`

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

"If there are gaps that are more than a few days" : 

Based on Apple's documentation it is 60 days :D : 
"Note: For billing-related issues, the App Store may attempt to renew a subscription for up to 60 days. You can check for a Subscription Retry Flag in the receipt to determine if the App Store is still attempting to renew the subscription."
( ref.: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html )

Comment: Additionally : I always receive the "pending_renewal_info" just for the latest purchase and nothing for the earlier ones.

Comment: Yeah, 60 days is theoretical maximum. Unless you capture really good information around the `pending_renewal_info` a user initiated cancellation and a processing failure look the same. Also, `pending_renewal_info` is per product identifier, not per transaction.